# Программа не может выйти из цикла

Tags: python, pandas, циклы

Есть программа:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time

flag = True
while flag:

    # информация  поездах
    a = [{'train_code': '887B', 'station': 'Lipki', 'time_arrive': time(12, 00)},
         {'train_code': '411C', 'station': 'Kyiv   ', 'time_arrive': time(10, 00)},
         {'train_code': '743L', 'station': 'Lipki', 'time_arrive': time(12, 00)},
         {'train_code': '113F', 'station': 'Rivne', 'time_arrive': time(11, 00)}]

    # вводим диапазон времени приходящих поездов

    start_time = time(hour=int(input("Enter start hours: ")), minute=int(input("Enter start minutes: ")))
    end_time = time(hour=int(input("Enter last hours: ")), minute=int(input("Enter last minutes: ")))
    s = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['time_arrive'])

    # проверяем прибытие каких поездов совпадает с заданым нами диапазоном

    for train in s:
        if start_time <= train.get('time_arrive') <= end_time:
            print(train)
            df = pd.DataFrame(a)
            res = df.groupby(["time_arrive", "station"]).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

    # если среди маршрутов есть такие, что приходят на одну станцию в одно и то же время, выводим ошибку и просим ввести новые данные

    for i in res["time_arrive"].to_list():
        if start_time <= i <= end_time:
            count = len(res)

            if count >= 2:
                print(f'There are {count} wrong destinations')
                print('Accident error. Choose the other time range please.')

                flag = True

            # если "ошибочных маршрутов" нет, прекращаем работу программы

            else:
                flag = False
                break
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при отсутствии "ошибочных маршрутов" программа все-равно запрашивает повторный ввод. Подскажите пожалуйста где я мог упустить что-то. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Этот код не запустится, потому что неправильно отформатирован.

Comment: @Эникейщик, не знаю, у меня в онлайн-компиляторе все запускается. А в чем, по вашему мнению, заключается неправильное форматирование?

Comment: В кривых отступах. Только не "по-моему", а по стандарту языка.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо за замечание, исправил. Как насчёт алгоритма выхода из цикла? Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: Видимо есть ошибочные маршруты

Comment: @Эникейщик не думаю, ведь при наличии "ошибочных маршрутов" программа выводит строку об ошибке. Когда их нет, строка об ошибке не выводится, но программа всё-равно просит повторный ввод данных.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105737/discussion-between-nc-6d-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, нашел нужное решение:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time

flag = True
while flag:

    # информация o поездах
    a = [{'train_code': '887B', 'station': 'Lipki', 'time_arrive': time(12, 00)},
         {'train_code': '411C', 'station': 'Kyiv   ', 'time_arrive': time(10, 00)},
         {'train_code': '743L', 'station': 'Lipki', 'time_arrive': time(12, 00)},
         {'train_code': '113F', 'station': 'Rivne', 'time_arrive': time(11, 00)}]

    # вводим диапазон времени приходящих поездов

    start_time = time(hour=int(input("Enter start hours: ")), minute=int(input("Enter start minutes: ")))
    end_time = time(hour=int(input("Enter last hours: ")), minute=int(input("Enter last minutes: ")))
    s = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['time_arrive'])

    # проверяем прибытие каких поездов совпадает с заданым нами диапазоном

    for train in s:
        if start_time <= train.get('time_arrive') <= end_time:
            print(train)
            df = pd.DataFrame(a)
            res = df.groupby(["time_arrive", "station"]).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
            count = len(res)

    # если среди маршрутов есть такие, что приходят на одну станцию в одно и то же время, выводим ошибку и просим ввести новые данные

    for i in res["time_arrive"].to_list():

        if (start_time <= i <= end_time) and (count >= 2):
                print(f'There are {count} wrong destinations')
                print('Accident error. Choose the other time range please.')
                break

                flag = False

            # если "ошибочных маршрутов" нет, прекращаем работу программы

        else:
                flag = False
                break
```

Программа не могла выйти из цикла, потому что res["time_arrive"].to_list() все время возвращало 2 аргумента, что в свою очередь триггерило соответствующее условие.